# How to force sql server to execute one command at a time without using GO?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I would like to make sure that a series of commands are executed in a serial way, like in

```
update TABLE1...
update TABLE2...
update TABLE3...
```

I would like that `update TABLE2` starts only when `update TABLE1` has completed.

Of course I can do this with GO:

```
update TABLE1...
GO
update TABLE2...
GO
update TABLE3...
GO
```

But in this case i will lose all the local variables.

Is there an easy way to perform what I need? Thanks.

Comment: In Oracle, it'd be an anonymous block (PostgreSQL just added support for this in v9).  I haven't come across anything similar in TSQL, you might need to create a stored procedure which contains the update statements, run the stored procedure, and then delete the stored procedure when you're done.

Comment: I am not seeing anything wrong with the update statements without the GO. That should just work as it is. Is that not so?

Comment: No, this is what I experienced, see my comment below.

Comment: It would have helped if the example you gave was closer to reality - that you were altering table structures, rather than just issuing UPDATE statements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need GO to do that; GO simply causes a batch to be sent to the server at that point. As long as you put the commands sequentially in one script, they will execute one-after-another just as you wish. You would have to do extra work to get them to run in parallel

Comment: This is not what I experience: for example I made a script that dropped 50 indexes, then used a cursor to do something on tables, than I recreated indexes again and I noticed that I got "cannot recreate index, it already exists" errors, because basically for some reason the commands where not executed sequentially. THat time I solved the problem by putting GO after the DROP indexes, Go after cursor operations. This is why I ask.

Comment: See AlexKuznetsov's answer for more about this. The commands ARE being run sequentially; they just can not be compiled because you can not submit a command to create an index that already exists. (even if that command batch is previously dropping that index.)

Answer (score 3):

Next command in your batch will begin only after the previous one has finished. No need to do anything, this is how it works. What is the problem you are solving?

Edit: your "cannot recreate index, it already exists" error occurs at compilation, not during running - your index exists when your batch is being compiled. GO breaks your script into separate batches, which compile only after the previous batch completed.

Comment: Please see my comment to Andrew Barber answer.